# Is there a way for git diff to check recursively through a folder and its subfolders

Tags: bash, git, git-diff

I've written a git hook to programmatically check the differences on a folder for certain commits. Unfortunately, it doesn't pass our use case because it doesn't check the contents of the subfolders within that folder; it just checks the file contents of the first folder. Is there a way for us to check the subfolders without explicitly writing git diff statements for both of them?

Our code:

```sh
dataChangedStr=$(git diff --quiet $oldrev $newrev -- config/extensions/ || echo changed)
```

We have two separate subfolders within `config/extensions` called `entity` and `typelist` that aren't checked for differences by the above statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to produce the list of directory paths to check for differences and invoke `git diff` on each of them:

```sh
find config/extensions -maxdepth 3 -type d -exec git diff --quiet $oldrev $newrev -- '{}' +
```

You can adjust the maximum level of recursion with the `-maxdepth` option.

Answer (score 0):

> I've written a git hook to programmatically check the differences on a folder for certain commits. Unfortunately, it doesn't pass our use case because it doesn't check the contents of the subfolders within that folder; it just checks the file contents of the first folder. ...

This is not the case.

It's worth noting here that Git doesn't actually store *folders* at all, but rather only files.  Git does, however, understand what it calls a *pathspec*, in which file names behave in a "folder-structured fashion".  So if commit A contains files named `config/extensions/entity/one.txt` and `config/extensions/entity/two.txt`, and commit B contains files named `config/extensions/typelist/one.txt` and `config/extensions/typelist/two.txt`, `git diff A B` will compare all four files.

The *results* of this comparison are a bit tricky, because `git diff` itself is a *user-oriented* command.  This means its behavior depends on user-specific configuration, which in turn means that it's unwise to use it in any *scripts* in which you want predictable behavior that's not dependent on user configurations.  But we can see that `git diff` does in fact check these things:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ mkdir config/ config/extensions/
$ mkdir config/extensions/entity
$ echo one > config/extensions/entity/one.txt
$ echo two > config/extensions/entity/two.txt
$ git add config/extensions
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) b36d1fb] initial
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 config/extensions/entity/one.txt
 create mode 100644 config/extensions/entity/two.txt
$ A=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
$ git mv config/extensions/entity config/extensions/typelist
$ git commit -m 'rename'
[master 02c48f6] rename
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename config/extensions/{entity => typelist}/one.txt (100%)
 rename config/extensions/{entity => typelist}/two.txt (100%)
$ B=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
$ git diff $A $B
diff --git a/config/extensions/entity/one.txt b/config/extensions/typelist/one.txt
similarity index 100%
rename from config/extensions/entity/one.txt
rename to config/extensions/typelist/one.txt
diff --git a/config/extensions/entity/two.txt b/config/extensions/typelist/two.txt
similarity index 100%
rename from config/extensions/entity/two.txt
rename to config/extensions/typelist/two.txt
```

Limiting the diff to `config/extensions` doesn't change the result, or the status:

```
$ git diff --quiet $A $B -- config/extensions || echo changed
changed
```

It's generally wiser to use `git diff-tree` here.  Using `git diff-tree` is often a bit harder because:

- it's not a command users are used to using, and
- it has different defaults from `git diff`.

In particular, it won't by default *recurse into* a directory to show you exactly *what* changed, merely dumping out the topmost "tree" entity that implies that there is something different in some files and/or sub-trees within the tree entry.  But in this case that just gives you a faster comparison, since all you want is the status:

```
$ git diff-tree $A $B
:040000 040000 e4532e3b5a1748d2fbc5a5a5b15525f9fd3b6817 434cdb32870dd0a387be437cc4de54df4af80ed3 M      config
```

and:

```
$ git diff-tree --quiet $A $B || echo changed
changed
```

In all cases, even with the user-dependent behavior of `git diff`, you should be getting the correct result here.  What's not clear to me, then, is what's actually going wrong with your test case.  A [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help a lot here.